# What to replace the Caps Lock key to?

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, remapping

I want to remap my Caps Lock key. I know how to do this, this is not a question about *How*, this is a question about *What*. I want to remap it to something useful, not just disable it.

What could I remap it to? Something to make life easier. Do you guys have any suggestions? This is not limited to regular keys; special actions (or anything that's mappable) are welcome.

Comment: All a matter of personal opinion. If you are going for uniqueness maybe consider CW.

Comment: Personally I would like it to print a 100 dollar bill every time I press it, ;-) Now that would make life easier!

Comment: @John T: I can't mark it as CW, I have to wait for a mod to come by.=/

Comment: Google's ChromeOS Cr-48 pilot laptop has a search key where the caps-lock key would be.

Answer (score 3):

Some games I play make use of the Tilde (`~`) for switching weapons. I find the Caps Lock key easier to get to quickly since the games make use of WSAD already, so I have it mapped to that. Even though the Tilde is only 2 keys above it, it is an awkward movement when you are aiming for speed.

Comment: I thought Caps Lock was used for crouch. Or have I just been away from games for too long?

Comment: Crouch is usually Ctrl in the games I play. I guess it depends on regional settings and keyboard layout... as well as which games :)

Comment: @Ignacio: You've been away from games for a little too long. =)  It's usually Ctrl now.

Comment: What are you playing where tilde is weapon change?  I'm used to tilde bringing up the console. ;)

Comment: A Counter-Strike fan I see? :)

Answer (score 2):

Playing a racing car sound, to remind you that Caps Lock is cruise control for cool.